# yii2, a way to show multiple nested views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have three models: Order, Customer and Company

When user is creating a new Order, he searches for existing Customer in Select2 widget, and if Customer doesn't exist, then creates a new one.

[image: screenshot of ui]

The "Create Customer" view is loaded in bootstrap modal widget. This part works well.

[image]

Then user searches for Company, and if he doesn't find it, he wants to add new one. I wanted to do it in the same way, by opening "Create Company" view in another modal window, but that approach doesn't work, since bootstrap doesn't support multiple modals (as far as I understand).

And I want to reuse existing views as much as possible.

The question is: how can I put multiple nested creation forms on one page?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to create more "active form" in the page each one connected to its own controller / action .. and possibly make them visible or hidden depending on your needs .. (eg: using tabs) 
you can incorporate the existing view using renderPartial or organizing the view along the lines of `_form` passing the related `$model...`

In the controller where you manage this composite form you must create and render  proper models for the different Models.